# How is the mapping done from .../script.php?one,1 to .../script/one/2?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

There is a PHP script which evaluates one or two parameters via QUERY_STRING. This script should process the parameters via QUERY_PATH. The PHP file type should be omitted.

Request of the form `https://example.org/script.php?bla,1` should be converted to `https://example.org/script/bla/1`.

I think the first part can be accomplished by using

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/script\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)(?:,(\w+))?$
RewriteRule .* /script/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

---

What must be done so that the script without file extension processes the forwarded request? I've tried Multiviews and ForceType - but to no avail.

*It is an Apache installation version 2.4. The PHP interpreter runs in CGI mode. There is only access to the .htaccess configuration.*

Comment: "This script should process the parameters via QUERY_PATH." - Do you mean `QUERY_STRING`? From your regex, it looks like the `,1` part is optional - is that correct? Presumably you have already converted any internal links to use the `/script/bla/1` URL form?

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for clarifying my request. Yes, I mean QUERY_PATH and yes, the second part is optional. All internal links are generated by a script. So it's just a question of the PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you have already changed any internal links to use the "new" URL of the form `/script/bla/1`. (Otherwise, you will still be exposing the "old" URL containing the query string and create unnecessary redirects for users and duplicate requests to your site.)

### Part One

*External redirect* from `https://example.org/script.php?bla,1` to `https://example.org/script/bla/1`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/script\.php$
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)(?:,(\w+))?$
> RewriteRule .* /script/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
> ```

Almost, except you will need an additional condition to prevent a redirect loop (for what we are going to do in the second part to rewrite the URL back to the actual filesystem path). We only want to redirect direct requests, not rewritten requests. We can do this by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable, which is empty on direct requests (and set to "200" after the first successful rewrite).

It is also more efficient to check the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, rather than using an additional condition that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable.

So, bringing this together we have...

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)(?:,(\w+))?$
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ /script/%1/%2 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Note that a trailing slash will be present if the value after the `,` (2nd parameter) is omitted.

If you are on Apache 2.4 then you can use the `QSD` flag instead of appending `?` to the *substitution*. This is preferable (for future development) as there are certain edge cases can result in a different response when simply appending `?`.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to a 301 once you have confirmed it works OK (to avoid caching issues).

### Part Two

*Internal rewrite* from `https://example.org/script/bla/1` back to `https://example.org/script.php?bla,1` (the underlying filesystem path).

> I've tried Multiviews and ForceType - but to no avail.

MultiViews will conflict with mod_rewrite in this instance. It will rewrite `script` to `script.php`, but without the query string.

You can do something like the following:

```
RewriteRule ^script/(\w+)/(\w*)$ /script.php?$1,$2 [L]
```

Note the absence of the `R` (`redirect`) flag. Providing you don't include a scheme+hostname then this will result in an *internal rewrite* - internal to the server, no external redirect.

Note also that the trailing slash, when the "2nd parameter" is omitted, is required. This matches the earlier directive that will always redirect to a trailing slash when the "2nd parameter" is omitted. This will only be an issue if your internal links do not include a trailing slash in such cases.

MultiViews needs to be disabled for this to work. It is not enabled by default on Apache, however, some shared hosts do enable this for some reason.

### In Summary

Bringing this together we have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "ugly" URL to "pretty" URL
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)(?:,(\w+))?$
RewriteRule ^script\.php$ /script/%1/%2 [QSD,R=302,L]

# Rewrite "pretty" URL back to "ugly" (real) URL
RewriteRule ^script/(\w+)/(\w*)$ /script.php?$1,$2 [L]
```

Comment: I have implemented everything as described - it works wonderfully! Especially interesting for me was the reference to the internal redirection. Many Thanks!